# add object names in json to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, object, json.net

May i know if it is possible to get only the object names in a json?? I download the following json string and upload to mysql, I now want to show the user with the object names whithin "Body": [ { "RowId": {...}}] in the json, The following is the json string,

**Sample removed**

I want to display the following which is within, "Body": [ { "RowId": {...,

**Sample removed**

in a listbox, so that the user can see befor it gets uploaded, is there a way i can accomplish this?? Thank you very much for the help :)

EDIT:

I want to extract the object names from the json thorugh a loop may be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code parses the JSON string and prints the values you are looking for:

```
// Choose appropriate names for these classes
class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Head { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Body { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> RowId { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{  **data removed - request from owner**} }]}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
    foreach (string value in result.Body.First().RowId.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

It's difficult to help you more, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve:
if you are trying to populate a WebForms [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx), you can create a list set the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) property.

Comment: YES! this is what i was wanting to do. :) thank you very much :) thanks again

Comment: may i ask what is the use of dictionary here?

Comment: @Hasitha you're welcome :) JSON.NET converts generic JSON objects to .NET dictionaries. You can read more about serialization in the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.NET to parse the JSON string, extracting the values that you are interested in, then place them within your ListBox.

I can't help much more than that because your question is terribly vague!

Comment: ohh, sorry if its too vague, but i dont know how to explain it further, i want to know how to extract all the object names i listed from the jason which is within "Body": [ { "RowId": {..}}] ..is it clear enough?? could help??

Answer (score 0):

its not directaly possible you have to make parser for it one hint for you a possible way to parse with key value pair

Comment: ohh, as in when creating the json?? if so I am out of reach because thi json is pre generated by a third party, sorry if i sounded dumb..because i am new to this :P :)